# display search results in haml syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

I am new to ruby and am having trouble implementing the view for search in haml syntax.

Here is my controller code for search which works fine

app/controllers/search

```
def search(text)
      @patients = @client.submit_search({ query: text, page: 1, page_size: 30 })
 end
```

This is my route in /config

```
match 'patients/index' => 'search/patients#index', via: :get
```

This is my views where in contains the form:

```
//Search Form
%h2 Patient Search
.search-form-elements
  %form{ :action => "", :method => "get"}

    %label{:for => "name"} First Name:
    %input{:type => "text", :name =>"first_name"}

    %label{:for => "name"} Last Name:
    %input{:type => "text", :name =>"last_name"}


    %label{:for => "name"}
    %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Search", :class => "button"}

  %table.table.table-bordered.table-condensed
    %tr
      %th
        Patient Name
      %th
        Id#
      %th
        Age
      %th
        Gender
```

Basically when I type some text and hit submit I want to display patient.name,patient.age etc in the above html table fragment .I do not want to show the html table if the result set is empty. but I am not sure how to implement this in haml format.

Comment: how do put the search parameters in the controller search function described above..basically i want to display the results in the same page when hit search

Comment: check this to implement simple search: http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

Comment: that seems lil different.how would call it in this case:%input{:type => "text", :name =>"first_name"}

Comment: Actually you can do it with only one field search and use this model. You should also re-edit your question because it's not what you were asking first...

Comment: assuming only one field(first name) was passed, how would the syntax look in the view to search and display

Comment: i tried this..but didnt work..@patients = @client.submit_search({ query: 'params[:first_name]', page: 1, page_size: 30 })

Comment: edited my answer so that it covers what you need, hope this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do that. I assume here that you have your list of patients on the index view.

In your view :

```
= form_tag patients_path, method: 'get' do
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
  = submit_tag "Search", :name => nil

- if @patients.present?
  %table.table.table-bordered.table-condensed
    %tr
      %th Patient Name
      %th Id
      %th Age
      %th Gender

    - @patients.each do |patient|

      %tr
        %td= patient.name
        %td= patient.id
        %td= patient.age
        %td= patient.gender
```

In your `Patient` controller:

```
def index
  @patients= Patient.search(params[:search])
end
```

And in your model:

```
def self.search(search)
  key = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    where('first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?', key, key)
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: use `present?` instead of `any?`: `nil.present? #=> false` but `nil.any? # => Undefined method 'any' for nil:NilClass` and `[].present? #=> false`